# Why in this example (got from msdn), in GetEnumerator method , new PeopleEnum returns IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Why in this example from MSDN, in `GetEnumerator` method, `PeopleEnum` returns `IEnumerator`?

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

public class People : IEnumerable
{
    private Person[] _people;
    public People(Person[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new Person[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }
   //why??? 
   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
       return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
   }

   public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
   {
       return new PeopleEnum(_people);
   }
}

public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public Person[] _people;

// Enumerators are positioned before the first element
// until the first MoveNext() call.
int position = -1;

public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
{
    _people = list;
}

public bool MoveNext()
{
    position++;
    return (position < _people.Length);
}

public void Reset()
{
    position = -1;
}

object IEnumerator.Current
{
    get
    {
        return Current;
    }
}

public Person Current
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return _people[position];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
BTW, if Array data type implements ICloneable interface, why msdn has copied pArray to _people by writing a for loop?

Comment: Actually, it is surprising that it does *anything* here - it could also just (as `IEnumerator`): `return _people.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: @Marc: Or for that matter it could derive from Collection<T> :)

Comment: @Josh - it looks like a 1.1 example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to return *exactly* `IEnumerator` to properly implement the `IEnumerable` interface. It is doing this using an "explicit interface implementation", so on the **public** API you see `PeopleEnum`, but `IEnumerable` is still happy

But in reality you would *very rarely* write an enumerator this way in C# 2.0 or above; you'd use an iterator block (`yield return`). See [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) chapter 6 (free chapter!).

For info, the reason that `PeopleEnum` exists *at all* here is that this looks like a .NET 1.1 sample, where that is the only way to create a typed enumerator. In .NET 2.0 and above there is `IEnumerable<T>` / `IEnumerator<T>`, which has a typed (via generics) `.Current`.

In .NET 2.0 / C# 2.0 (or above) I would have simply:

```
public class People : IEnumerable<Person> {
    /* snip */
    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable<Person>)_people).GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return _people.GetEnumerator();}
}
```

Comment: Actually "never" is too harsh. Like never use a goto - yield is SOMETIMES a LITTLE slower, so in RARE EDGE CASES there is a case for not using yield. But again, this is REALLY rare, so no -1 here, just a note.

Comment: @TomTom - revised to "very rarely" ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Types implementing IEnumerable require a method called GetEnumerator that returns an IEnumerator. In that example (which is pretty obsolete as of C# 2.0) there is an enumerator class PeopleEnum that implements IEnumerator. It's what's used internally by the C# foreach statement.

A more up to date example would look more like the following. Note there's no longer a need for a PeopleEnum class now that C# supports iterators. Effectively the compiler does all the heavy lifting for you.

```
public class People : IEnumerable
{
    private Person[] _people;
    public People(Person[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new Person[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
       for (int i=0; i < _people.Length; i++) {
           yield return _people[i];
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I personally can't even remember the last time I implemented IEnumerable directly. I was just pointing out the fact that enumerator classes are largely extinct now.

Comment: I wrote one recently, but to support C# 1.2 ;-p